# SQL table - name each row

Tags: sql, sql-server, rows

I am trying to write a query that adds names to each row of my table. It seems like it should be simple but I can't figure it out since I'm not an expert at SQL.

Here's what I want my table to look like:

```
         New    Cancels Net
Daily     0         1   -1
Weekly    0     1   -1
Monthly   25    34  -9
Quarterly 25    34  -9
Annually  535   552 -17
Total     3418  1398    2020
```

Here's my table now:

```
New     Cancels Net
0           1   -1
0           1   -1
25          34  -9
25          34  -9
535         552 -17
3418    1398    2020
```

Here's the query behind it (I'm using SQL Server Management Studio):

```
SELECT [New Orders]
      ,[Cancels]
      ,[Net]
FROM [DailyFigures]
WHERE [UID]  IN (
SELECT TOP 1 [UID]
FROM [DailyFigures] 
ORDER BY [UID] DESC)
UNION ALL
SELECT [Orders]
      ,[Cancels]
      ,[Net]
FROM [WeeklyFigures]
WHERE [UID]  IN (
SELECT TOP 1 [UID]
FROM [WeeklyFigures] 
ORDER BY [UID] DESC)
UNION ALL
SELECT [Orders]
      ,[Cancels]
      ,[Net]
FROM [MonthlyFigures]
WHERE [UID]  IN (
SELECT TOP 1 [UID]
FROM [MonthlyFigures] 
ORDER BY [UID] DESC) 
UNION ALL
SELECT [Orders]
      ,[Cancels]
      ,[Net]
FROM [QuarterlyFigures]
WHERE [UID]  IN (
SELECT TOP 1 [UID]
FROM [QuarterlyFigures] 
ORDER BY [UID] DESC) 
UNION ALL
SELECT [Orders]
      ,[Cancels]
      ,[Net]
FROM [AnnuallyFigures]
WHERE [UID]  IN (
SELECT TOP 1 [UID]
FROM [AnnuallyFigures] 
ORDER BY [UID] DESC) 
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM([Orders]) AS Orders, SUM([Cancels]) AS Cancels, SUM([Net]) AS Net FROM [AnnuallyFigures]
```

I was thinking of adding a column with the row count and somehow changing the row count from numbers to names, but I'm not sure how to do that. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you simply add a constant, such as 'Daily' to your select clause and change the union all to a union, Bob might be your uncle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a 'text string' for each individual select like this:

```
SELECT 'DAILY' as ' ', [New Orders],[Cancels],[Net]
FROM [DailyFigures]
WHERE [UID]  IN 
  (SELECT TOP 1 [UID] FROM [DailyFigures] ORDER BY [UID] DESC) 

UNION ALL

SELECT 'WEEKLY' as ' ', [Orders],[Cancels],[Net]
FROM [WeeklyFigures]
WHERE [UID]  IN 
  (SELECT TOP 1 [UID] FROM [WeeklyFigures] ORDER BY [UID] DESC)

UNION ALL

SELECT 'MONTHLY' as ' ', [Orders],[Cancels],[Net]
FROM [MonthlyFigures]
WHERE [UID]  IN 
  (SELECT TOP 1 [UID] FROM [MonthlyFigures] ORDER BY [UID] DESC) 

UNION ALL

SELECT 'QUARTERLY' as ' ', [Orders],[Cancels],[Net]
FROM [QuarterlyFigures]
WHERE [UID]  IN 
  (SELECT TOP 1 [UID] FROM [QuarterlyFigures] ORDER BY [UID] DESC) 

UNION ALL

SELECT 'ANNUALLY' as ' ', [Orders],[Cancels],[Net]
FROM [AnnuallyFigures]
WHERE [UID]  IN 
  (SELECT TOP 1 [UID] FROM [AnnuallyFigures] ORDER BY [UID] DESC) 

UNION ALL

SELECT 'TOTAL' as ' ', 
    SUM([Orders]) AS Orders, 
    SUM([Cancels]) AS Cancels, 
    SUM([Net]) AS Net 
FROM [AnnuallyFigures]
```

Comment: originally, I just copied the query and used the union all, then after looking at it, I removed it.  I've used just UNION in my own stuff (not union all), but the previous comment made me think to remove it.  Maybe it should have stayed in?

Comment: I see no reason why this should be a union. A union will attempt to remove duplicates, and since you have a different constant on each row, this doesn't seem necessary - unless there is a terrible normalization problem inside any of the individual queries feeding the union.

Comment: I agree ... I just re-read some explanations on UNION vs. UNION ALL, and agree 100% with you.  I'll fix the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Wow that was really easy, I'm not sure why I didn't know how to do that. Thank You!!!

Comment: I modified the answer so that it will show blanks for the column heading ... obv. you could make it say whatever you'd like...